# Snowflake using REPEAT/SPACE inside VALUES clasue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Simple scenario table with single column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t1(c VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO t1(c) SELECT repeat('a',100); -- works 
INSERT INTO t1(c) VALUES (repeat('a',100)); -- error

INSERT INTO t1(c) SELECT space(100); -- works
INSERT INTO t1(c) VALUES (space(100)); -- error

SELECT c, LENGTH(c) FROM t1;
```

> SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [LPAD('', CAST(100 * (CAST(LENGTH('a') AS NUMBER(18,0))) AS NUMBER(21,0)), 'a')] in VALUES clause

Is there a limitation which expressions/function calls could be used with `INSERT ... VALUES` or is it simply a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that those expressions would be simple string functions, but looking at the way the compiler translated the function, it no longer appears to be a simple function.

> Most simple arithmetic expressions and string functions can be evaluated at compile time, but most other expressions cannot.

Why don't you use variables?

```
set my_spaces=(SELECT space(100)); 
set my_aaaa= (SELECT repeat('a',100)); 

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t1(c VARCHAR(200)); 

INSERT INTO t1(c) SELECT repeat('a',100); -- works 

INSERT INTO t1(c) VALUES ($my_aaaa); -- works

INSERT INTO t1(c) SELECT space(100); -- works 

INSERT INTO t1(c) VALUES ( $my_spaces ); -- works

SELECT c, LENGTH(c) FROM t1;
```

Comment: Fair enough. Will this limitation be lifted in the future(or the only workaround is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`?